# S4 app testing wont overwrite drawables

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm trying to test an app on a Galaxy S4 and I need to manually uninstall the app every time before launching it for it to overwrite an old drawable ( bottleoverlay.9.png) and I think sometimes that doesn't even work. It seems to be this specific file that doesn't want to update. If i update the drawable-xxhdpi version of another png file it changes it on the phone after an uninstall but not the bottleoverlay.9.png file
bottleoverlay.9.png is quite large 400 x 1000 px could this be the problem?

It works fine with an S2. How do I fix it so it to overwrite the old drawables in the apk

--I found that in the bin folder the bottleoverlay.9.png file is still the old one so I deleted it and that seemed to update it.

--now its not updating the files even if i change the bin version and uninstall

Comment: This sounds more like a problem in your build environment that happens to have been exposed on the S4. What does your manifest look like and what is your resource directory structure? Where is bottleoverlay.9.png being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what was happening was the xxhdpi 9patch file was too big and it was reverting to xhdpi and hdpi files aswell as a non9patch version of the xxhdpi file. I still don't quite know how it was choosing which file but thats why it wasn't showing my updated files. I ended up just deleting the xxhdpi file and now it resorts to the xhdpi file and scales it up. Although when the xxhdpi file was there when it was resorting to the other files it was not scaling them.

Answer (score 0):

try that code to install your new app:

~..\sdk\platform-tools\adb -d install -r "the path of your apk file"

It will overwritten all the old stuff.